# insertId shows as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

Im trying to print last insert Id but it always prints as undefined

Here is API code:

```
app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
  connection.query(`INSERT INTO tradeoffers (DCID, DCNAME, CATEGORY, IGN, ITEM1, Q1, ITEM2, Q2) VALUES ("${req.body.dcid}", "${req.body.dcname}", "${req.body.ign}", "${req.body.category}","${req.body.item1}", "${req.body.q1}", "${req.body.item2}", "${req.body.q2}");`, (err, result, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err
    else res.send(result)
  })
})
```

Here is request code:

```
                  axios.post('http://localhost:60/post', {
                    dcid: interaction.user.id,
                    dcname: interaction.user.username + '#' + interaction.user.discriminator,
                    category: category,
                    ign: ign,
                    item1: iyh,
                    q1: quantityiyh,
                    item2: iyw,
                    q2: quantityiyw
                  })
                  .then(async function (response) {
                        console.log(response.insertId);

                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
```

When I print only *response* variable it shows right data:
[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpSqa.png)

but when I try to print only last inserted id it shows as undefined

Comment: Look at your response, it has data.... You are not looking into that object, you are one level above that. You are looking for `{ insertId: 1 }` and it is `{ data : { insertId: 1 } }`

Comment: ure right what a shame on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response variable contains a field called `data` which has the `insertId` in it, along with the other values you are passing via the API. You are currently specifying the wrong path to the variable you want.

Instead, use this:

```js
console.log(response.data.insertId)
```